# How to set up a custom 404 page on Google app Engine (go)

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a google app engine project (go) and don't really like the default 404 page. I've built a custom 404.html page and placed it in my root but can't for the life of me work out how to redirect 404 errors to this custom page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to read the documentation about [app.yaml Reference, error_handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref?hl=en#Python_app_yaml_Custom_error_responses)

```
Example
error_handlers:
  - file: default_error.html

  - error_code: over_quota
    file: over_quota.html
```

Comment: thanks. I thought that only worked though for specific error codes but not 404 Not Found? i.e. default|over_quota|dos_api_denial|timeout